# add variable to page.url.templateArgs

Tags: javascript, url, alfresco, aikau

I need to add variable to result from `page.url.templateArgs` my actual result is:

```
{"pageid":"dp","webscript":"site/testSite/powerdoc"}
```

I need this:

```
{"pageid":"dp","webscript":"site/testSite/powerdoc","site":"$siteName"}
```

I know that `page.url.templateArgs` take result from url, but I don't know how to get what I want, I can't change url and I can't just assign `page.url.templateArgs.site` or `page.url.templateArgs["site"]`, I already tried that.

Maybe it is impossible, but there has to be someway to do this.

myURL:

> http://localhost:8081/share/page/dp/ws/site/$siteName/powerdoc#useBillYear=false&billYear=2016&type=all&company=all&state=all&project=all

I have a value of $siteName ready in my script but i don't know how to add it as result of  `page.url.templateArgs.site` . I need this because of default code in alfresco. Everything is based on `page.url.templateArgs.site`, i can't override all methods because i never found them all.

I need something like this:

```
page.url.templateArgs["site"]=function(){
    if(model.siteName == null){}
        var res = (args[1]).split("/");
        model.siteName=res[2];  
    }
    return model.siteName;      

};
```

But this gives me error. :(

If i change url like this:

> http://localhost:8081/share/page/dp/ws/site/testSite/powerdoc#useBillYear=false&billYear=2016&type=all&company=all&state=all&project=all&site=testSite

The problem is still the same.

webscipt.get.desc.xml:

```
> <webscript>    <shortname>Page for PowerDoc filtering - page to handle
> browsing of company documents</shortname>   
> <url>/site/{site}/powerdoc</url>    <format
> default="html">argument</format> </webscript>
```

I found this:

```
page = { url: { templateArgs: { site: url.templateArgs.shortname}}};
```

now i only need to use my `model.siteName` beside `url.templateArgs.shortname`

Comment: Why not add a `${sitename}` to your url param?

Comment: i can do that but it has no affect, it will appear in args[], but not in the result from 'page.url.templateArgs.site'

Comment: I don't think, you can do write operation like page.url.templateArgs["site"]= something. As @Gagravarr  suggested, can you use ${sitename} or similar?

Comment: I really dont think so i can use what @Gagravarr suggested, everywhere in default code is 'page.url.templateArgs.site' and i really need to point thi to siteName directly. I have siteName ready but i can't override it everywhere :(

Comment: Tell me on which page / webscript do you want to use? Let me help you.

Comment: It's my page created through AIKAU, you can see whole url in the description of my question it's myURL.